# Unable to find default theme files in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme

I installed Magento 2 and also migrated my categories, products, attributes etc from `Magento 1.9.2.2` to `Magento 2.0` successfully. Now I need to work on my existing theme and want to migrate it for `Magento 2.0`. I read many blogs and articles about `Magento 2.0 theme development`, however, I can't find default theme files in `app/design/frontend/Magento` to get an idea about the structure of `Magento 2.0` themes.

Kindly help me out with this. Share some tutorials or methods to develop `Magento 2.0` theme.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While it's an important topic in general, ultimately it seems there's just an issue of incomplete download.

Comment: @benmarks no brother there's no issue with incomplete download since I found all the theme files on the locations decribed by Marius in below answer :)

Comment: I see. Reopened.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you got your Magento 2 instance from github, you should find the files in `app/design/frontend/Magento`. If they are not there, you can try to get them again.
If you downloaded Magento 2 from `https://www.magentocommerce.com/download` you should find the theme in `vendor/magento`.

- `theme-frontend-blank` is the blank theme
- `theme-frontend-luma` is the luma theme.

Comment: Oh, now I got it. Thank you so much. I downloaded it from https://www.magentocommerce.com/download and yeah I successfully got default theme files. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Please read the Magento 2 official documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/bk-frontend-dev-guide.html. There you can find everything about creating your own theme.

As a good example you can review the Magento Blank and the Magento Luma theme. You can find these in the vendor folder in the root of your Magento installation under magento/theme-frontend-luma or blank.

Comment: Yeah I read that tutorial but I was unable to find default theme files and you answered it, Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

After migration i have same issue,
I did following steps to solve it,

- go to admin : >content > design > configuration and select default theme (Magento/luma)
- and run following query in db manually,

  UPDATE `cms_page` SET `custom_theme` = '' WHERE `cms_page`.`identifier` = 'home'
- Also ,run following command

  1. php bin/magento indexer:reindex
  2. php bin/magento cache:clean
  3. php bin/magento cache:flush

Answer (score 0):

Having tweaked Magento 1 sites a good bit, I was left quite frustrated trying to make even the simplest of changes to M2. I just bought Alan Storm's "book" + package [No Frills Magento 2 Layout](https://store.pulsestorm.net/products/no-frills-magento-2-layout). I haven't read much yet, but seems to be more understandable than trying to read documentation from Magento.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't found your desired theme in the app\design\frontend...

Go to vendor\Magento\theme_name

Comment: Location of the source files are `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-*`. Blank is under `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank`

Comment: So, what is the difference between my answer and your comment?